# A number doesn't change after updating it in setState(), it is called in a constructor

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Context**

I have an application in Kotlin (native Android) and it sends data to an attached module in Flutter. From Kotlin I send **_numA2F**, and  I want to show it on flutter view, but it isn't working. The other variable (_numF2A) that I'm going to send back to the native app is getting updated properly.

**Question**

Could you please point out why _numA2F isn't taking the value received from the native android application? I already confirmed that the number that I send from Kotlin is received in the flutter module.

This is my code in Flutter:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in a Flutter IDE). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _numA2F = 1;
  int _numF2A = 1;

  static const platform = const MethodChannel('com.jssm.af/data');

  _MyHomePageState() {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(_receiveFromHost);
  }

  Future<void> _receiveFromHost(MethodCall call) async {
    int number = 11;

    try {
      print('CHECK THIS OUT!!!!!!!!!');
      print(call.method);
      if (call.method == "fromHostToClient") {
        final String data = call.arguments;
        print(call.arguments);
        final jData = jsonDecode(data);
        number = jData['numA2F'];
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      _numA2F = number;
      print("_numberA2F: " + _numA2F.toString());
    });

  }

  void _doubleNumber() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _numF2A = 2 * _numA2F;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('REBUILDING!!!!!!!!!!');
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Data received from fa_Android',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_numA2F',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              'Number to be returned (double):',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_numF2A',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _doubleNumber,
              child: const Text('Send Result to Android',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where you are calling this function `_receiveFromHost`

Comment: I call it in _MyHomePageState()

Comment: Did you solve this problem? @Stiven

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
_MyHomePageState() {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(_receiveFromHost);
  }
```

And use an initState function like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
  _receiveFromHost(call);
}
```

or better still use:

```
_MyHomePageState() {
    _receiveFromHost(call);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Man, it didn't work. The thing is that when I press the button y call `_doubleNumber()` and update another variable, and it works, but at that point, the variable `_numA2F` value is **1**. That's the original value that I set on the declaration of the variable and not the value that I receive from the native Android app.